# LINQ - Querying about 6000 unique records by WHERE clause

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I've got a problem and no idea how to solve it. Imagine you have a `List<int>` with about 6000 unique id's that matches the id's of a table with about a million records in a sql datatable. I want to select those 6000 records that matches those id's via LINQ from my c# program. I don't want to use `Contains()` because it gets very slow in translation and the argumentlist gets to big.

Any other ideas how to solve this ?

---

Something about my scenario ( this is not the real but a similar scenario ) :

I've got a Service that is connected to a database. A Client requests a batch of Items like a Person for example. The Service accepts the requests, query the DB and sends the data back to the client.

Person = (PersonID , Prename, Lastname)

Now the Client holds a temporary List of Persons. With an additional method I would like to retrieve the adresses of these Persons from the service. So I put a List of PersonID's to the service that should give me back a list of Adresses that have references to those persons.

Comment: Are subsets of the id's likely to be consecutive? e.g. [1-5, 10-12, 14, 19-32]

Comment: Is there a way to rephrase your query, such that you don't have to send the ID's (like is there a join, or subquery that you can use such that you resolve the 6,000 id's on the server)?

Comment: If those 6000 ids you select from another table then why not to write a sql Stored proc use those IDs and return the results of stored proc to client ?

Comment: Would it be possible to post your code and some more info? For example, are you using LINQ to SQL? If you are, it might be possible to allow LINQ to create an optimized query for you. I don't really see how you can not send the list of IDs over to SQL, but it might be possible to structure the query in an optimized way...

Comment: I only have the id's so a subquery is impossible to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework (EF) you can use inner join between your data (data) and your table (Customers)

```
void Main()
{    
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 6000);

    var result = from x in data
    join y in Customers
    on x equals y.CustomerID
    select x;

    result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: I am indeed using EF. If this really works it would be great ! I think I already read about a similar solution a while ago. I will try this

Comment: The code that I provided is working, I just ran it from LINQPad.

Comment: Do you know how it technically works ? How does the sql command look like ?

Comment: I am not sure if EF will translate it to SQL expression tree, you will need to look at SQL profiler.

Comment: Your solution works indeed. However I think this can get very slow with very high amount of data. I think technically linq querys the whole table and then joins it on clientside. But this was a good solution for me thank you !

Comment: You might be right, I checked and LINQ to SQL doing this way, but I am not sure how EF will do it.  If you have chance to look at profiler, let me know how it work.  It is good to know.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't recommend this. As great a tool as LINQ is, there are some scenarios where trying to get smart with your data by handling it code-side could be quite detrimental to the application performance.

You've got a list of these Id's somewhere, if they are in the database, why not do the whole operation as a stored procedure and just return the results, That way you're not having to push an expensive query across the wire, it's all in your database, so you minimise traffic, and likely increase responsiveness.

6000 items might not seem like a lot to bother with this for, but realistically as you said, it can be a bit of a nightmare of performance when trying to do a select with datasets of size.

Comment: Alternatively, if they're in the database already, just expose that table/proc via the LINQ model and "join" to it.  That'll get you the merged result you're looking for.  If not - I agree with Matthew - a custom procedure to load a table variable & do the join in SQL, by hand, will probably be a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

Insert the 6000 IDs into a temporary table and join that temporary table to your million record one.

Use Contains() and select in batches of n, where N = 500, 1000, etc. instead of all 6000 at once.

Using Contains() is going to make linq to create a very big SQL statement.

Comment: You beat me to it +1.  We had to use a similar technique with ADO.net a long time ago (using batches).  At that time, we did some experimenting, and we found that 1,000 items in the batch was the tipping point (for either Oracle or SQL Server, can't remember which).  If you kept the argument list below 1,000, performance was pretty good.  It degraded significantly above 1,000 at a time.

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean a SQL temp table, or a C# list of objects? If you are suggesting doing this on the SQL end, wouldn't you lose the benefits of set theory doing this? I can see LINQ straining under a load like this, but the SQL engine is optimized for large set queries...

Comment: @JMarsch - We have had the pain of discovering that as well.  One app I worked on created dynamic SQL (pre-linq) and some of the contains clauses were very big or would eventually run out of memory.  You can increase the query memory usage as a temporary stopgap measure, but in the end we redesigned using temporary tables to get over the limit.

Comment: @CarmonBute - Temporary table (table variable) in SQL.  SQL does has its limits, even with queries.  I suspect a very large parameterized sql string is being passed to sql server.  That string can only be so big, if its too big, you get an out of memory error back.

Comment: LINQToSQL and such use sp_executesql.  It uses nvarchar(max) as the datatype.  That is limited to a 2GB string on 64bit servers. Filling a temp table still involves sending INSERT statements to fill the data, or sending XML blob.  LINQ, as used in LINQtoSQL, is a fancy form of StringBuilder.  LINQ won't choke on string generating a list of 6000 integers.  You are talking a total size of like <100K of string data.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I've found that xml performs best for large IN criteria for IDs. It also gets around the 2100 max parameters in SQL Server, which you'll hit if you do a Contains in LINQ.

I would suggest:

- make List
- serialize to Xml
- create a stored procedure called ContainsXYZ that takes the xml as a parameter
- have your stored procedure use xpath to extract the Ids and join on it
- assuming you're using Entity Framework, you can map this stored procedure, execute it, then materialize the results into regular entities.

Comment: I can confirm that XML parser is the fastest way of reading an array from a parameter compared to parsing of comma or space separated string.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get this out of the way...

```
 var joinTry = from company in dc.Companies
               join id in list on company.CompanyID equals id
               select company;
```

Doesn't work.  LinqToSql won't let you join.  "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

```
 var containsTry = from company in dc.Companies
                   where list.Contains(company.CompanyID)
                   select company;
```

Does work.  In the predictable

```
SELECT [t0].[CompanyID], [t0].[CompanyName]
FROM [Company] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CompanyID] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, ...
```

way...  As dirty as this is, there is seriously no faster way to get a list of ints to a SQL server.  The overhead time of any call is seriously larger than any parsing.

```
SELECT
    c.CompanyId,
    c.CompanyName
FROM Company c
    WHERE CompanyID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

...is the same execution speed as... (Generated by LINQ)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[CompanyID], [t0].[CompanyName]
FROM [Company] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CompanyID] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9)',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 int,@p5 int,@p6 int,@p7 int,@p8 int,@p9 int',@p0=1,@p1=2,@p2=3,@p3=4,@p4=5,@p5=6,@p6=7,@p7=8,@p8=9,@p9=10
```

...and is Twice as fast as...

```
SELECT
    c.CompanyId,
    c.CompanyName
FROM Company c
        /* @Test is a table variable with 1-10 in it */
    INNER JOIN @Test t ON t.ID = c.CompanyID
```

You really don't need to optimize SQL server's handling of a list of integers.  In the IN() solution, SQL puts the integers in an index it generates on the fly ANYWAY.

The real question should be... "What and I representing with a list of 6000 integers?" and "Should I put this list in a table?".  Any solution that takes client-side list of 6000 integers, and sends it to the server, will be >= in overhead than a solution that uses Contains(). If you use LinqToSQL, you sort of have to sell out to the paradigm to a certain extent.

If this still makes you feel dirty, You might try creating a table for arbitrary restriction lists.  Two columns, both ints.  Then you can insert your IDs into that table, then just use...

```
var searchTry = from company in dc.Companies
                join search in dc.SearchLists on company.CompanyID equals search.ValueID
                where search.SearchID == savedSearchID
                select company;
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Your first case works but you got to do it in the other direction. 

from id in list
               join companys in dc.company on id equals companys.id
               select companys;

Comment: @KroaX, no, you are wrong! If you want to use translation to SQL instead of selecting all the records from DB, you wave to start LINQ expression from using EF dataset and then join anything else. Doing select from your list and then joining EF DbSet you will force selecting all the records!